# How to include a calendar in RangeSelector's date input in Highstock?

Tags: input, calendar, ionic3, highcharts

I build a chart using the Highstock and Ionic 3, like this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highcharts-stock

In RangeSelector there are 2 boxes ("from" and "to").

I'd like to know how to include a calendar in each box? Like this:

[date input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxAcX.png)

I'm new to Ionic development and would like to see an example code using Angular 5, please. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ionic `DateTime`. You may need to customize for yourself. It has many functionalities. You can use like below:

```
// in .html file
    <ion-col class="search-text-input">
       <ion-item id="SearchDate" class="right-float">
            <ion-datetime
                [(ngModel)]="dosDate"
                displayFormat="{{dateFormat}}"
                min="1900-01-01">
            </ion-datetime>
       </ion-item>
     </ion-col>

// in .scss file
.search-text-input {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.search-text-input ion-item#SearchDate {
  border-radius: 2mm;
  padding-left: 2mm;
  height: 10mm;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

// in .ts file
export class HighstockPage {
    dosDate: string;
    dateFormat: string;
    constructor() {
       this.dosDate = '';
       this.dateFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY';
    }
}
```

Reference: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/

You can also use [ionic3-calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic3-calendar) package for your project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know ionic DataTime, however I do not know how to implement it inside inputDate using TypeScript.  Could you show me a example code, please?